# Определение парадигмы и коррелята

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

> Когда человек плачет, он просто не хочет, чтобы кто-нибудь был сопричастен его слезам.

Я сделала так:

- В 1-й придаточной части (*"Когда человек плачет"*) коррелят невозможен, парадигма несвободная.
- Во 2-й придаточной части (*"чтобы кто-нибудь был сопричастен его слезам"*) коррелят невозможен, парадигма свободная.

Верно ли определены парадигмы и корреляты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что во второй придаточной части (изъяснительной) при наличии союза ЧТОБЫ требуется определенная форма глагола, чтобы обозначить модальность: не хочет - был (бы) сопричастен. Тогда парадигма несвободная.

С остальным можно согласиться.

Comment: спасибо!  я тоже сомневалась насчет этого!